# Whats the limit of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ where $a_n=n^{-1/2017}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Draw the first 5 terms, in order to guess the limit of the sequence, then prove what you guessed is correct. The sequence is  $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ $a_n=n^{-1/2017}$

$a_1=1$ $a_2=0.999656$ $a_3=0.999455$ $a_4=0.999312$   $a_5=0.999202$

How am I meant to guess the limit? Or is there something I'm not thinking about and missing?

Comment: $a_n = \frac{1}{n^{1/2017}}$. Does that help? What happens as $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let k>0 and $n \rightarrow +\infty$ thus

$$n^{-k}=\frac{1}{n^k} \rightarrow 0 $$

Comment: $k>0{}{}{}{}{}$.?

Comment: oh yes sorry for the typo :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer to your question:"How am I meant to guess the limit?"

You are meant to observe that the sequence decreases, that it is positive, and to ask yourself will it ever stop decreasing? Then you are meant to try to prove something. There is nothing stopping for you for examining other integers. You could try $n=1000000000000$, or $10^{1000000}$ and see that the number that you get is quite small. That could help in answering the crucial question: "will it ever stop decreasing"? You could also try to prove directly that the sequence is monotone.

That's how you are meant to guess the limit.

Comment: For $n=1000000000000$, the number you get is $0.9863943367546181458256012462986$. Is that quite small?

Comment: It is smaller than all the previous ones, which might help you guess that maybe, just maybe, the sequence is decreasing. You could also try $n+1$, if you like.

Comment: That is whats confusing me, even for $n=10^{99}$ the answer is $0.8931351954$

Comment: Would you have a reasonable conjecture at this time?

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition of limit, 0 is the limit if $\lvert a_n-0 \rvert < \epsilon$ for $n >>1$. Thus $\lvert \frac{1}{n^{1/2017}} \rvert < \epsilon$, $$n> \frac{1}{\epsilon^{2017}} $$

Answer (score 1):

One way to attack this kind of problem is to ask yourself whether the precise value $2017$ is likely to matter. Here, probably not. So think about the problem for $n^{-1/2}$ and $n^{-1/3}$  . That should give you grounds for a good guess, maybe even a proof.